# How to join results of two SQL result tables of different sizes

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012, inner-join

I have two result sets from queries that both have a common MessageLogID int. I want to inner join and take the larger list of tbl1, and only return rows that match the tbl2 rows on the MessageLogID int key. The issue that I am seeing is that the tbl1.messagelogid cannot be bound because it can't see the tbl1 and tbl2 tables that is selected.

```
  select
 (select messageLogId, localName, action, remoteName, localHost, dateTime,  message from Messagelog as mm where (message like '%error>%' or message like '%   <nak status ="1">%')
  ) as tbl1,

  (SELECT *  FROM 
 (
  select substring(m.message, charindex('<MessageID>', m.message)+11,   charindex('</MessageID>', m.message)-charindex('<MessageID>', m.message)-11) as   SQLmessageID from messagelog m 
  where message like '%<NCPDPID>1234567</NCPDPID>%' and dateTime > '3/01/2016'
 ) a JOIN 
 (
  select 
  substring(r.message, charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)+20,    charindex('</RelatesToMessageID>', r.message)-charindex('<RelatesToMessageID>',    r.message)-20) as SQLRelatesMessageID, 
  message, 
  messagelogid from messagelog r
  where 
  dateTime > '3/01/2016' AND 
  message LIKE ('%<RelatesToMessageID>%</RelatesToMessageID>%') 
  and message LIKE ('%<Error>%</Error>%') 
 ) b ON b.SQLRelatesMessageID = a.SQLmessageID)
  as tbl2

  from messagelog where tbl1.messagelogid = tbl2.messagelogid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something in this form:

```
with tbl1 as (select ...), tbl2 as (select ...)
select tbl1.*
from
    tbl1 inner join tbl2
        on tbl2.MessageLogId = tbl1.MessageLogId
```

You could also do it this way which is closer to what you appeared to be attempting:

```
select tbl1.*
from
   (select ...) tbl1
   inner join
   (select ...) tbl2
       on tbl2.MessageLogId = tbl1.MessageLogId
```

Comment: Thank you so much.